# Internet Explorer having problems with special chars in querystrings

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, url, encoding, utf-8

**This is not a *new* queestion**

There are quite a few of questions here on SO about IE having some problems with handling special characters in the querystrings. In all of the cases it is the same: Chrome, Firefox, Safari (everyone) handles the UTF-8 encoded URLs correctly, almost all of them even handles the cases where the IRIs aren't encoded into URLs. But IE insists on make life hard for the developers.

As I have run into the problem myself, and have worked quite a bit with it. To me it seems that IE for some reason insists on decoding the UTF-8 encoded URL into ISO-8859-1 before sending it to the server.

**My case**

I am a resident in Denmark, and therefor I have to work with the danish letters æøå.
There a many cases where I want to send parameters from my views into some C# methods. Two examples of such places where the special characters often pop up:

1. Searching
2. Specification of filename for a downloaded files

Say a Dane wants to search for the danish word "æblegrød" (special kind of apple pie). In Chrome and Firefox, if I just feed the browser with the IRI:

```
http://example.com/Search/QuickSearch?searchQuery=æblegrød
```

The query sent to the server would look like this:

```
http://example.com/Search/QuickSearch?searchQuery=%C3%A6blegr%C3%B8d
```

In Internet Explorer however it would look like this:

```
http://example.com/Search/QuickSearch?searchQuery=Ã¦blegrÃ¸d
```

It is now easy to see what the problem is. 
Firefox & Chrome are URL encoding the URLs

> ... each byte that is not an ASCII letter or digit to %HH, where HH is the
>   hexadecimal value of the byte
>
> http://www.w3.org/International/O-URL-code.html

Where Internet Exlorer instead is doing a direct UTF-8 encoding of the string, resulting in "Ã¦blegrÃ¸d". This is also the same end results as if you take a UTF-8 string and decode it as if it was ISO-8859-1, is this a coincidence?

**I have tried some things**

As Internet Explorer has the option to "send URL path as UTF-8" I tried disabling that. Changing nothing.

As it went wrong when IE has to handle "searchQuery=æblegrød" I tried encoding the IRI before handing it to the browser. Resulting in all browsers getting the following URL to work with:

```
http://example.com/Search/QuickSearch?searchQuery=%C3%A6blegr%C3%B8d
```

IE however doesn't care, what I see in the networking log is still the URL

```
http://example.com/Search/QuickSearch?searchQuery=Ã¦blegrÃ¸d
```

being sent to the server.

**This is how my configuration is:**

1. Files are saved as UTF-8
2. I set the meta tag:

   ```
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   ```
3. IE sends URL-paths as UTF-8 (also set IE to
   do this for intranet querystrings)
4. Globalization set to UTF-8

   ```
   <globalization          
       uiCulture="da-DK"
       culture="da-Dk"

       fileEncoding="utf-8"
       responseEncoding="utf-8"
       requestEncoding="utf-8"
       responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" />
   ```

I am running out of ideas, I don't know what it is that I am doing wrong. I am leaning towards IE creating the havoc, but I genuinely do not know if it is something that I have set up wrongly in my project.

Comment: What you are encountering is a known problem with many versions of IE, including 11. See [Unicode in URL changes for IE11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/04/22/internet-explorer-11-unicode-utf8-url-query-string-international.aspx) and [encoding of query string parameters in IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220057/), for instance.

Comment: `Ã¦blegrÃ¸d` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `æblegrød` when viewed as ISO-8859-1. IE is encoding the querystring to UTF-8 correctly, it is just transmitting the UTF-8 as-is (most likely because your HTML page's charset is UTF-8) instead of hex-encoding the non-ASCII byte octets in `%HH` format, like other browsers do.

Comment: This issue might be related to how IE submits HTML forms, as described in this MSDN blog article: [Brain Dump: International Text](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/07/13/internet-explorer-and-international-text-encoding-unicode-punycode-ansi-oh-my.aspx). Note: "*URLs in IE may use up to three (!!) different encodings at once: punycode in the hostname, %-escaped UTF-8 for the path, and **raw codepaged-ANSI for the query** and fragment components. This is clearly a mess, but fixing it to match the IRI specification incurs compatibility costs. (Trust me, we’ve tried!)*".

Comment: Basically, there is nothing you can really do to change IE's behavior.  This is just how it works. You are not doing anything wrong on your end.

Comment: @RemyLebeau if there is nothing I can do to change IE's behavior, is there then something I can do to work either around or with it?
As I can understand, EricLaw says that I should be able to work with "properly encoded" URLs, but trying that, I get what you also said "Ã¦blegrÃ¸d is the UTF-8 encoded form of æblegrød when viewed as ISO-8859-1" (also mention in the "I have tried some things" section)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An answer to the future people hitting this question.

Playing around with this, I got to the conclusion that the only thing I could do was to encode all of my URL's, and then work with the Content Disposition ([with help from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)) to make it work for different browsers. The solution is not perfect, it still has some flaws, but it is the best approach I have found so far.

In all of my cases, the links were build with JS, so [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is my go-to method to encode the URLs.