# FRAME src attribute: Do I have to URI-encode the value?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, frame, urlencode, frameset

Are there any requirements / specs regarding the `src` attribute of a `FRAME`, especially if I have to **URI-encode** (percentage encoding) its value by myself (within HTML)?

It looks like Internet Explorer does a faulty encoding for some characters (0x encoding instead of percentage encoding) here (resulting in a `400 Bad Request` server response), while chrome/firefox encode such a 'frame src'-URL properly and work.

Example HTML code which reproduces a 400 response on IE 11 but works on other browsers (you might need to bypass some browser security protections due to same-origin/cross-site restrictions):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<FRAMESET>
<FRAME src="https://www.stackoverflow.com?param=ÖÄÜ"/>
</FRAMESET>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML is designed to be resilient and browsers are expected to try and fix everything wrong they find. So your coding does not **need** to be correct. However, relying on browsers being able to recover from error conditions makes things less predictable.

Answer (score 3):

The 400 response in IE 11 is due to IE doesn't encode the url parameter correctly. In IE 11 the parameter sent is like below which is not right:
[image]

The encoded parameter which is right in Chrome should be like this:
[image]

I also find that if we check `Send UTF-8 query strings` in Internet Options, the parameter will be encoded correctly and the example will work in IE 11:

[image]

So the issue is that `param=ÖÄÜ` is not encoded to UTF-8 in IE 11. I think it will be better if we encode all the urls for IE. Besides, [`<frameset>` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset), you could use `<iframe>` instead. The working sample code in IE 11 is like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://www.stackoverflow.com?param=ÖÄÜ"></iframe>
    <script>
        var mysrc = "https://www.stackoverflow.com?param=ÖÄÜ";
        document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src = encodeURI(mysrc);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit:**

I also try to find some official docs about this, but there seems nothing. But I find some related threads:

[encoding of query string parameters in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220057/encoding-of-query-string-parameters-in-ie10/18220123#18220123)

[Internet Explorer having problems with special chars in querystrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391124/internet-explorer-having-problems-with-special-chars-in-querystrings)

If you refer to the threads, you'll find that EricLaw also says:

> The behavior isn't fully documented anywhere.

> We cannot reliably use URLs which are not properly encoded in Internet Explorer.

As we can't control if the users has checked the `Send UTF-8 query strings` in IE and I refer to the threads above, I came up with the solution: **The best approach is to encode all the urls in IE.**

Comment: Interessting, especially that IE setting. Why I get 400 in IE, is perfectly clear to me. However, your answer is still lacking whether a src attribute can or must be percentage-encoded (ideally, by citing more or less official specs) in order to fix that properly (or to realize that the IE is buggy if it's not).

Comment: Hi @MRalwasser I think you need to percentage-encoded the urls in IE. Please see my edit.