# Servlet hebrew (UTF-8)

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8

I tried to send hebrew paramaters in link on IE like this:

```
localhost:8080/test?g=שלום
```

שלום = Hebrew text

I set in my tomcat server.xml:

```
useBodyEncodingForURI="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

and in my web.xml this filter:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>set character encoding</display-name>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.Moh.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param> 
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

com.Moh.SetCharacterEncodingFilter :

```
package com.Moh;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;

/**
 * Set the character encoding of the request to as set in "encoding"
 * this should be done before the request is accessed.
 */
public class SetCharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {
    private String encoding;

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException{
        encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
        if( encoding==null ) encoding="UTF-8";
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next)
            throws IOException, ServletException{
        // Respect the client-specified character encoding
        // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
        if(null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        /**
         * Set the default response content type and encoding
         */
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        next.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy(){}
}
```

but when i debug my servlet with the paramaters i got gibberish
like this:
øôð-à

I tried use this:

`String str = new String(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Windows-1255");`
but got "????"

and

`String str = new String(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");`
and got "Ã¸Ã´Ã°-Ã"

what can i do?

Comment: You shouldn't have Hebrew in the link. It should be encoded there already. Don't trust IE to encode it in the correct encoding.

Comment: @RealSkeptic tnx for your answer but i cant encode the text in the link, this is a third party software that send the links like that and can't change it

Comment: AFAIK browsers will encode url parameters using URLencoding, i.e. your hebrew parameter would then be encoded as `%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D`. Thus you could try to decode that using `URLDecoder.decode( parameter, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: @Novaterata all of them... and in chrome its working perfect because its encode automatic or something like that

Comment: So you need to check which encoding the software uses. Please include a real example URL (already encoded).

Comment: Have a look at this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2014/04/22/unicode-in-url-changes-for-ie11/

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220057/encoding-of-query-string-parameters-in-ie10/18220123#18220123

Comment: @Novaterata ok tnx i will look that

Comment: @Novaterata your link solved my problem, i set in IE settings to send utf8 query string and its worked